# Nonempty sets in $\mathcal{B} ( \mathbb{R}^{[0, \infty)})$ are not contained in the set of continuous functions

Tags: analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

I am reading a book in probability theory, which claims that the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B} ( \mathbb{R}^{[0, \infty)})$ on  $ \mathbb{R}^{[0, \infty)}$ is so "small" that it does not include even the space $C[0,\infty)$, which is the space of continuous functions from $[0, \infty)$ to $\mathbb{R}$. To be precise, it says that

> The only $\mathcal{B} ( \mathbb{R}^{[0, \infty)})$-measurable set contained in $C[0,\infty)$ is the empty set.

By definition, $\mathcal{B} ( \mathbb{R}^{[0, \infty)})$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the collection of cylinder sets of the form
$$ \{ \omega \in \mathbb{R}^{[0, \infty)} \, | \, (\omega(t_1), \ldots, \omega(t_n)) \in A \},$$ where $t_i \in [0, \infty)$ and $A \in \mathcal{B} ( \mathbb{R}^n)$.

Intuitively, this definition suggests that $\mathcal{B} ( \mathbb{R}^{[0, \infty)})$-measurable sets are only determined by countably many coordinates, whereas a continuous function is determined by uncountably many values. But I do not know how to prove this rigorously. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your title doesn't really make sense. A set in $\mathcal{B}\left(\mathbb{R}^{\left[0,\infty\right)}\right)$ is automatically a subset of $\mathbb R^{[0,\infty)}$ wich on its turn is a set of functions. Such **set** cannot be expected to be a continuous function.